# Функции железа и ОС

Tags: linux, железо, ос, bios, uefi

Прошу пояснить некоторые вещи, которые я опишу ниже. Я много читал о том, как загружается система, какие функции выполняет железо, какие - система, но пока что полной картины сложить не могу.

Итак. Как я понимаю, при загрузке системы сначала просыпается bios. Он проверяет все железо, делает диагностику. Когда он решит, что все нормально, он считывает 512 (не уверен) первых байт с диска, проверяет 2 "магических" байта, и если они говорят о том, что этот диск - загрузочный, то bios начинает выполнять код загрузчика, т.е. этих 510 байт. При этом начинает выполнять не сразу, а записав их по некоторому адресу в оперативную память. Здесь вроде все понятно. А еще как процессор адресует память - постранично - вроде тоже понятно.

А теперь то, что мне непонятно: допустим, я загружаю linux. Загрузчик с диска поднял grub, grub загрузил ядро, ядро начало выполняться. Окай. Но как ядро адресует память? Получается напрямую физическую? Ну т.е. без виртуальной. Тогда другой вопрос. Получается весь user-space код, который адресует виртуальную память, выполняется в некой "песочнице" ядра, которая позволяет транслировать адреса виртуальные в физические? Или же есть какие-то именно процессорные механизмы? И как работает uefi?

В общем, меня интересует то, какие возможности предоставляет процессор, да и железо в целом, а что реализовано на системном уровне, и если можно, то почему оно так работает.

И да, еще интересно, как процессор общается с различным железом вроде видеокарт, и какие интерфейсы он предоставляет для управления этим железом программно.

Comment: @KryTer_NexT управление памятью не относится к тематике stackoverflow, ну что вы, конечно.

Comment: "при загрузке системы сначала просыпается bios" - тащемта нет. Сначала с шансами просыпается мультикронтроллер, который проверяет всякие там питания, кнопку включения и т.д. Процессор стартует последним и начинает выполнение кода из BIOS

Comment: [How Computers Boot Up](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/how-computers-boot-up/) нормальный материал (только на англ.), кроме этой статьи советую почитать предыдущие и следующие (пока не надоест)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Загрузка кажется только простой, правда, это очень сложный и многошаговый процесс, я постараюсь Вам описать его. Хоть это и будет похоже на маленькую книжку, но я надеюсь, что **многим будет интересно это почитать**.

### Вы нажали кнопку питания

Линия PS_ON замыкает на "землю" и происходит подача питания на все железо! **ОНО ОЖИЛО!**. Блок питания включен. Начинается тестирование блока питания на соответствие всех напряжений требованиям. В случае удачного завершения данной операции, спустя 0.1-0.5с, вырабатывается сигнал Power Good, свидетельствующий о том, что загрузку компьютера можно продолжать. Головки жесткого диска выходят из парковочной зоны, остальное оборудование включается...**ПОЕХАЛИ!**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Блок питания проверился, а что дальше?

Дальше на специальный вход центрального процессора подается сигнал сброса (Reset). Процессор обнуляет содержимое своей памяти и начинает работу.

### В чем заключается начало работы процессора?

Системная память сделана так, что первая команда которую будет считывать процессор после сброса находится в BIOS. Это инструкции по проведению самотестирования. Программа POST выполняет тестирование процессора, оперативной памяти, чипсета, видеосистемы, накопителей, системы управления питанием, клавиатуры, портов LPT и COM (а также подключенных к ним устройств), других компонентов компьютера.

### POST завершился, что делать дальше системе?

После того как успешно завершилась процедура POST, вызывается программное прерывание BIOS INT 19h и запускается процедура поиска загрузочного сектора порядок поиска которого установлен непосредственно в BIOS.

### Теперь будем искать загрузочную запись?

Да, но сначала немного терминологии, без которой дальше делать нечего:

> **Сектор** - минимальный участок хранения информации на жестком диске
>   равный 512 байтам;
>   **MBR (Master Boot Record)** - Главная загрузочная запись, она находится в
>   нулевом секторе диска и по сути является загрузочным сектором жесткого
>   диска;

Дальше с указанного жесткого диска BIOS`ом считывается главная загрузочная запись MBR и управление дальнейшей загрузкой передается ей. Далее микропрограмма, находящаяся в MBR, сканирует таблицу разделов на наличие активного загрузочного раздела, после того как системный раздел будет найден, MBR загружает в память компьютера его нулевой сектор и выполняет код находящийся в нем. Загрузочный сектор раздела содержит код операционной системы, которую нужно загружать. В случае, когда на жестком диске нет системного раздела, BIOS отобразит сообщение об ошибке. Если системный раздел будет найден, загрузка продолжится. Все вышесказанное относится к запуску абсолютно любой операционной системы.

### Хочу загружать Windows!

А теперь, если вы например загружаете WINDOWS, после всего вышесказанного, загрузчик ntldr который находится в системном разделе считывает из загрузочного файла boot.ini информацию о количестве операционных систем и их расположении, и предлагает пользователю выбрать из списка операционную систему.

### Система выбрана!

Отлично, загружаем ядро в память, система готова к работе, но как же ядро управляет распределением памяти?

### Что представляет собой ОЗУ?

Логически ОЗУ представляет собой упорядоченный (одномерный) массив элементов. Элементы (минимальные адресуемые единицы МАЕ) пронумерованы, причем номер каждой МАЕ фиксирован и определяется схемотехнической реализацией устройства памяти. Номер элемента реально существующего в системе устройства памяти в дальнейшем будем называть адресом (Address) этого элемента. В каждой такой ячейке может храниться двоичное слово фиксированной длины

### Распределяем память

И так, адресная шина процессора работает...**Нет, это слишком долго..** Будем считать, что процессор работает с диапазоном последовательных адресов от нуля до максимально доступного в системе адреса (в зависимости от количества оперативной памяти) и может при необходимости обратиться к любому байту в этом диапазоне.

Если сгенерировать для программы адреса, как они расположены в физическом виде, без виртуальной, то одновременное выполнение двух программ **просто невозможно** из-за перекрывания данных одной программы другой. Например, компилятор генерирует адреса для виртуального адресного пространства заданного диапазона, а устройство управления памятью, **называемое диспетчером памяти**, транслирует виртуальные адреса, сгенерированные компилятором, в адреса ячеек, расположенных в физической памяти. **Компилятору нет необходимости знать**, в какое место в памяти ядро потом загрузит выполняемую программу.

> Конечно же виртуальная память сама по себе ничего не хранит.
>   **Виртуальное адресное пространство** — это просто абстракция, но оно
>   определенным образом поставлено в соответствие физической памяти. 
>   Отображение виртуальной памяти на физическую осуществляется через
>   аппаратно реализованные страничные таблицы. **Аппаратная часть**
>   непосредственно выполняет отображение, **а ядро управляет таблицами и их
>   конфигурацией, алгоритмами замещения и т.д.**

[image: Память]

**Диспетчер памяти, это не какой-то процесс!** Это устройство и оно может находиться на микросхеме процессора или на отдельной микросхеме рядом с процессором.

Вы обратились на какой-нибудь 32 битный адрес, то модуль разделяет его на 20 разрядный адрес страницы и 12 разрядное смещение внутри страницы. Все это называется прозрачной работой с памятью, когда программист даже не подозревает о существовании страничной организации памяти. Хотя, есть страничная организация памяти с процессом сегментации, при котором программисту требуется знать о существовании сегментов.

### UEFI

Код микропрограммы UEFI написан на C и выполняется в современном 64-битном режиме. По сути это полноценная операционная система, которая  работает на неограниченном уровне доступа к ресурсам "ring 0". Выполняется фаза PEI, и DXE перед загрузкой. Я не вижу смысла здесь все это описывать, вот картинка вам:

[image: UEFI]

**Источники:** IBM.com, Habrahabr.ru, Overclockers.ru, Таненбаум Э. "Архитектура компьютера"

*Для более четкого понимания работы компьютера и решения ваших вопросов, присоединюсь к ответу **@AlexanderBlinov**, прочитайте Архиктуру компьютера, очень полезная книга.*

Comment: Только больно уж она занудная (а что поделать? Старый профессор старой школы). ([здесь веселее](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/how-computers-boot-up/), а если почитать предыдущие и следующие посты, то не очень-то и упрощено)

Comment: @avp А мне понравилось, да есть моменты занудства..но за-то очень фундумантальная и без пичканья на всех страницах примерами ассемблера без комментариев! :) Спасибо за ссылку, там следующая статья интересная про Kernel Boot Process :)

Answer (score 2):

В рамках StackOverflow невозможно развёрнуто ответить на Ваш вопрос, хотя он весьма интересен.

Для получения ответа рекомендую Вам прочитать книгу ["Архитектура компьютера" Э. Таненбаум, Т. Остин.](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/20032936/) В данной книге Вы найдёте ответы на эти вопросы.

Крайне интересная и полезная литература. В принципе, в Сети есть pdf этой книги, найти его несложно.

Comment: Еще "Современные операционные системы" от Эндрю Таненбаума тоже очень интересная и полезная книга. На одном дыхании читается, эта книга вне конкуренции :)